# How to re-arrange a tibble by a column according to a custom list?

Tags: r, tibble

So let's say we have the following arbitrary tibble:

```
Header_A  Header_B  Header_C
 1          A          10
100         A          15
 10         F          C
 K          B          Q
```

Now, let's say we have the following list `order = c('B','F','A')`. I am wondering how to go about re-arranging the tibble by `Header_B` according to the order in `order`. In other words, this would be the expected output:

```
Header_A  Header_B  Header_C
 K          B          Q
 10         F          C
 1          A          10
100         A          15
```

The internal order of A does not matter. I'm a very inexperienced user of R so I don't really know how to go about it. I was trying to just re-arrange the tibble by descending alphabetical order of B by calling `tibble %>% arrange (desc('Header_B'))`but nothing changed.

In Python equivalency, if this were a dataframe, it would be possible to accomplish this by `sort_values(by='header_B), key=order`. I guess I am looking for something similar.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: `tibble %>% arrange(factor(Header_B, levels = order))`

Comment: `left_join(data.frame(Header_B = order), 
          df, by = "Header_B")`